# Changing index of summation. $\sum_{y=1}^\infty (1-\theta)^{y-1}\theta$

Tags: summation

I am always confused how to change the index of summation.

$$\sum_{y=1}^\infty (1-\theta)^{y-1}\theta$$

The above is supposed to be a geometric sum and sum up to $1-(1-\theta)^x$? But how?

Comment: Try to let $y-1 = z$. For the lower bound $y=1$, this is equivalent to summing from $z =0$.

Comment: The upper bound of summation is $x$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your upper bound of summation $x$? If yes, set $n=y-1$. $y$ takes the values $1,2,3,\dots x$, so $n$ will take the values $0,1,2,\dots x-1$. So, $$\sum_{y=1}^x(1-\theta)^{y-1}\theta=\sum_{n=0}^{x-1}(1-\theta)^n\theta=\theta\sum_{n=0}^{x-1}(1-\theta)^n=\theta\frac{(1-\theta)^x-1}{(1-\theta)-1}=1-(1-\theta)^x.$$

Comment: How did u get from the 3rd expression to the 4th? I think its something to do with the upper limit of the sum being $x-1$ instead of $x$ ... but how?

Comment: This comes from the geometric series: the sum of $a^n$ for $n=0,\dots k-1$ is $\frac{a^k-1}{a-1}$.

Comment: Oh ... ic ... the formula I had is just $\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k = \frac{1}{1-z}$. When I try to work out $\sum_{n=0}^{x-1} z^n = \frac{1}{1-z} - (z^x)$? Reason being: $\sum_{n=0}^{x-1} z^n = \sum_{n=0}^{x} z^n - z^x$?

Comment: It's easier to see this from the identity $$a^k-1=(a-1)(a^{k-1}+a^{k-2}+\dots+a+1).$$Then, you divide with $a-1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{y=1}^x(1-\theta)^{y-1}\theta$$
more precisely
$$\sum_{y=1}^{y=x}(1-\theta)^{y-1}\theta \tag{1}$$
Now the equation of lower bound
$$y=1 $$
can be transformed to
$$y-1=0$$
and the equation of the upper bound 
$$y=x$$
to
$$y-1=x-1$$
by subtracting $1$ from the equation.
We get
$$\sum_{y-1=0}^{y-1=x-1}(1-\theta)^{y-1}\theta \tag{2}$$
In this expression we substitute $y-1$ by $y$ to get
$$\sum_{y=0}^{y=x-1}(1-\theta)^{y}\theta$$
This substitution is only correct if all old $y$ are substituted by new $y$. This is more clear if in $(2)$ you first substitute $y-1$ by $z$

$$\sum_{z=0}^{z=x-1}(1-\theta)^{z}\theta$$
check if all $y$ have disappeared and now substitute $z$ by $y$
$$\sum_{y=0}^{y=x-1}(1-\theta)^{y}\theta$$

A sligthly other way to process $(1)$.
We want to change $y-1$ to $z$ so we set
$$y-1=z$$
and from this we get 
$$y=z+1$$
Substituting this in $(1)$ we get

$$\sum_{z+1=1}^{z+1=x}(1-\theta)^{(z+1)-1}\theta $$

and this can be transformed to

$$\sum_{z+1=1}^{z+1=x}(1-\theta)^{(z+1)-1}\theta $$
or better

$$\sum_{z=0}^{z=x-1}(1-\theta)^{z}\theta $$
You can change the variable name from $z$ to $y$ and get
$$\sum_{y=0}^{y=x-1}(1-\theta)^{y}\theta$$

Answer (score 1):

You can see change of variable more clearly if you write the summed terms out:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{y=1}^x (1-\theta)^{y-1}\theta
 =& (1-\theta)^{1-1}\theta + (1-\theta)^{2-1}\theta+(1-\theta)^{3-1}\theta + \cdots + (1-\theta)^{x-1}\theta\\
 =& (1-\theta)^0\theta + (1-\theta)^1\theta+(1-\theta)^2\theta + \cdots + (1-\theta)^{x-1}\theta\\
 =& \sum_{z=0}^{x-1} (1-\theta)^z\theta
\end{align*}$$
The remaining is simply a geometric sum, as you have noted.